# Compiler added optimization causes different behavior for "final" methods

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, final

```
struct B { 
  virtual void foo ()
  { cout << "B::foo()\n"; }
};

struct D : B { 
  void foo () //final
  { cout << "D::foo()\n"; }
};

int main ()
{
  B *pB = new B;
  D *pD = static_cast<D*>(pB);
  pB->foo();
  pD->foo();
}
```

Outputs expected behavior:

```
B::foo()
B::foo()
```

If we make the `D::foo()` final, then the output is pleasantly different:

```
B::foo()
D::foo()
```

Which means that `virtual` functionality is not kicked-in when the method is invoked with pointer/reference of a class which has that method declared as `final`.
Also it means that, `final` isn't just a compile-time check but also contributes to runtime behavior.

Is it a standard behavior for all compilers. I have tested with g++4.7.

**Edit**:
Spawned a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190743/compiler-added-optimization-causes-different-behavior-for-final-methods) with clarification. Closing this question.

Comment: You are casting a base-class pointer _that actually points to a base-class object_ to a derived-class pointer. That isn't valid.

Comment: Wait... you can downcast from parent to child? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Mysticial: You could. If the parent pointer's dynamic type was that of a child, of course.

Comment: @Xeo I obviously mean if the type is of the child. But that's not the case here.

Comment: Your code is just invalid. That's really all there is to say. `pB` is not a pointer to a `D`. Casting it to one just gives nonsense.

Comment: You have completely changed the nature of the question now. Now it's about whether the virtual call will be optimized away; before it was about unexpected behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I have given the explanation for: *Why I gave the example with bad code earlier?*. I was aware of unexpected behavior, wanted to see the effect of virtual function optimization.

Comment: @iammilind: My point is that, by changing the nature of the question so radically, you made all of the existing answers *invalid*.

Comment: @NicolBolas, you are right, though it was not intended by me, but due to change in the question the answers have become irrelevant. I have [spawned a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190743/compiler-added-optimization-causes-different-behavior-for-final-methods).

Answer (score 11):

```
D *pD = static_cast<D*>(pB);
```

With this statement, you gave up the right to having sane program behavior. C++ does not *require* this operation to work if what `static_cast` is given is not actually of type `D` or one of `D`'s derived classes (which it isn't).

So it's not optimizations that are thwarting you, just bad code.

There's a reason why `dynamic_cast` exists; a proper `dynamic_cast` would have quickly failed on this, returning `nullptr` for an illegal cast.

Comment: prior to C++11 casting from object pointer to function pointer was undefined behaviour, does it mean that using `GetProcAddress` or `dlsym` for obtaining function pointer you gave up the right to having sane program behaviour? Clearly it's virtual call optimization affects the output, the question does not anyhow concern undefined behaviour.

Comment: "*prior to C++11 casting from object pointer to function pointer was undefined behaviour*" I'm pretty sure that's still true in C++11. "*does it mean that using GetProcAddress or dlsym for obtaining function pointer you gave up the right to having sane program behaviour?*" `GetProcAddress` returns a *function pointer*, so you don't have to invoke undefined behavior. As for `dlsym`, *yes*, the C++ standard does not define what happens, and thus you no longer have the protection of the C++ standard in the code you write. You are therefore relying on undefined behavior.

Comment: "*the question does not anyhow concern undefined behaviour*" That's because he *changed the question* after I answered it.

Comment: you get undefined behaviour with GetProcAddress when you obtain address of a variable, anyhow, just like with dlsym your program will behave in a documented and predictable way, you won't lose 'sane behaviour' with these functions.

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin: "*behave in a documented and predictable way*" Just not documented and predictable *by the C++ standard.* That is what we're talking about here; the C++ language. It says that *anything* can happen at this point, optimal, sub-optimal, or just plain wrong. Or, more to the point, show me a piece of compiler documentation (not source code; actual documentation) that says that this cast will produce defined behavior from that compiler.

Comment: To me the question was clear enough even in first edition. Honestly, it looks like nobody tried to really understand the question as soon as they found UB there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18984/discussion-between-konstantin-oznobihin-and-nicol-bolas)

Answer (score 5):

You're entering the realm of undefined behaviour since you're accessing an object through a pointer / reference to a type that is not the actual type of the object.

`3.10 [basic.lval] p10`

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object
> - [...]

The dynamic type of `pB` is `Base*`, obviously, but the dynamic type of `pD` is *still* `Base*`.

Answer (score 3):

You're invoking undefined behavior here. You can't just downcast a pointer arbitrarily.