# Compiler added optimization causes different behavior for “final” methods

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, final

I had asked a post with the [same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170189/compiler-added-optimization-causes-different-behavior-for-final-methods). But due to misinterpretation, all the answers were discussing if it's a valid code/behavior or not.

However the main question is about, if the optimization will kick-in or not ?

With reference to the linked post, see the genuine case:

```
D *pD = new D;
pD->foo();  // `D::foo()` is `final`
```

Will all the compilers optimize `pD->foo()` call by not kicking-in virtual mechanism ?

[Note:
*Why I gave the example with bad code in earlier question?*
I am aware that, casting from base to child in above way is not a good code. Main intention was to check if the Java-like optimization for final happens or not and the first way was the only way one can verify it without going down to assembly.
]

Comment: You'd need to survey each and every one of the current C++ compilers to answer this. I don't believe the standard mandates optimizing this out, so it's up to each implementation.

Comment: When the static type is equal to that most-derived overrider, I see no reason why the compiler would bother with a vtable lookup. It's not even important here that `foo` is `final`, since `D` is the most-derived class, and as such there can be no other function to call. Now if you had a `struct DD : D{};`, my first point applies again, since `D` is the most-derived overrides thanks to `foo` being made final. But really, it's a quality of implementation issue, as such not really a good fit for SO I think.

Comment: Not only that, but it will likely change as time goes on. Some compilers that don't optimize it today may get a patch that adds optimization in tomorrow. Some compilers that do optimize it may change when it gets optimized or even remove it. So it's ultimately too localized.

Comment: @Xeo, it's possible that `final` could be important here. If you see the earlier post, the difference happens when function is invoked with `final` with g++4.7. I remember that in Java the `final` has the exactly same effect. I am just curious to know, if you find it's not a good fit, you may want to flag for close.

Comment: Well... my simple test case with Clang inlined the whole thing. This question is pretty hard to answer in general though.

Comment: @Xeo: compiler can't always know if `D` is the most-derived class, even if it has global optimization you can load a new module with a new class at run-time.